# "since two months ago"?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

My students write sentences like this:

> She hasn't gone out with him since two months ago.

so I want to know if this sentence is right or wrong in English grammar.

Comment: Related:[“I've been working here since two months ago”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95062/ive-been-working-here-since-two-months-ago) and [Is using “since” and “ago” with the present perfect correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284067/is-using-since-and-ago-with-the-present-perfect-correct) But both questions are closed.

Comment: It sounds unusual to me—but still grammatically correct. Something that isn't wrong, but that you would be advised to rephrase. (It goes against any style I can think of.)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is understood what the student is saying, in my opinion, it does sound incorrect. This is mainly due to the use of 'since' in her example.

'Since' is often used as word to identify a **specific** time reference, however two months ago is not specific. This has to do with Present Perfect Tense.

Ago is a reference to the past, whereas Since is a reference to a period, or specific time.

This pattern of speech is quite uncommon in today's spoken English. It is also dependent on what the speaker wishes to emphasise.

A native English speaker may prefer to say "It has been two months since they have gone out together."

"They stopped dating two months ago, and haven't been going out since."

Alternatively : "She hasn't seen him since the last time they went out together, which was two months ago."

Answer (score 0):

It looks and sounds odd because we don't usually use 'ago' with present perfect. 
'Ago' is usually used with the simple past. 'I saw him two years ago'.

In the present perfect we refer to time with 'for' and 'since' in the following way: for + amount of time/ since + exact time.

We expect to see things like 'for two years' and 'since 1985'. 
I hope that helps.